# Closing subtasks launched with asyncio.ensure_future

Tags: python, python-asyncio

If I have the following:

```
async def foo():
    for i in range(10):
        print "1"
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

async def bar()
    t = asyncio.ensure_future(foo())
    while not t.done():
        print("waiting")
        await asyncio.sleep(0.5)

async def baz():
    t = asyncio.ensure_future(bar())
    await asyncio.sleep(2.5)
    t.cancel()
```

And `baz()` is called in a larger event loop, how can I make sure that foo() is cancelled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `try/finally` block would catch the [CancelledError](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.CancelledError) exception:

```
task = asyncio.ensure_future(foo())
try:
    [...]
finally:
    task.cancel()  # return False if task is already finished
```

Some [task functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#task-functions) already handle the cancellation of subtasks:

```
result = await asyncio.wait_for(foo(), 60.)  
result, = await asyncio.gather(foo())
```

In both examples, `foo()` is wrapped in a task and would be canceled automatically if the parent task were to be canceled.

---

**EDIT**

Here's a simple example of a coroutine controlling the execution of another one:

```
async def control(coro, timeout=1.):
    task = asyncio.ensure_future(coro)
    while not task.done():
        try:
            print("The task is not finished yet")
            await asyncio.wait([task, asyncio.sleep(timeout)], "FIRST_COMPLETED")
        except asyncio.CancelledError:
            task.cancel()
    return task.result()  # Raise task.exception() if any
```

Now, `await control(foo(), 1.)` should work exactly like `await foo()` (regarding cancellation, exception and result) except it prints `The task is not finished yet` every second until `foo()` is done.

Comment: I guess I missed a requirement here - I'd like to also trigger any exceptions thrown by the subtask to be thrown in the current task

Comment: @Eric Then why not simply use `await task` or `await foo()`?

Comment: Because I want to watch other things and cancel the task early

Comment: @Eric Once the task is done, using `await task` or `task.result()` would instantly raise the `task.exception()` if any. Would that work?

Comment: But that would always raise at least a `CancelledError`, right? Can I safely swallow that, or will that make the swallowing task sometimes uncancellable?

Comment: Shouldn't I wait until the subtask acknowledges the cancellation?

Comment: @Eric I think you have a point; I changed my example so the task doesn't stop if the subtask is not finished. This is how `await task` and `await foo()` work as well.

Comment: Not quite sure whether calling `.cancel` multiple times is valid, but I guess this has the nice property of forwarding however many times it is called to the subtask

Comment: @Eric It is valid actually, see the docstring and comments in [Task.cancel()](https://github.com/python/asyncio/blob/master/asyncio/tasks.py#L192): `[...] it may be a Task that catches and ignores the cancellation so we may have to cancel it again later.`